# 1D-CNN , " expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions "

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have implemented 1D-CNN model which mentioned in [this paper](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mt6QjSweEV2Eo6y4YIBW_s-VeX-cAU18) and when tested parameters of my model ,  [Summary of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOp4f.png)

It's exactly what mentioned in the paper but when use `model_1D.fit` it gives me this error :

```
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-58726d6ca642> in <module>()
      1 model_1D.summary();
      2 #model_2D.summary();
----> 3 model_1D.fit(X_train1 , y_train1,epochs=100,validation_data=( X_valid1,y_valid1))
      4 #model_2D.fit(X_train2 , y_train2,epochs=100,validation_data=( X_valid2,y_valid2))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    129                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    130                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 131                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    132                 if not check_batch_axis:
    133                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4723, 128000)
```

Here's code :

```
from keras import Model , Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv1D, MaxPooling2D, Reshape, Concatenate, Dropout , MaxPooling1D, Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.optimizers import Adam
# ----------------------- 1D CNN ----------------------
model_1D = Sequential()
# 1
model_1D.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size= 5 , strides=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(128000,7380))) # input shape after preprocessing
model_1D.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 4, strides=4))
# 2 
model_1D.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size= 5 , strides=1 , activation='relu'))
model_1D.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 4, strides=4))
# 3
model_1D.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size= 5 , strides=1 , activation='relu'))
model_1D.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 4, strides=4))
# 4 
model_1D.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size= 5 , strides=1 , activation='relu'))
model_1D.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2, strides=2))
# 5
model_1D.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size= 5 , strides= 1 , activation='relu'))
model_1D.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2, strides= 2))
# 6
model_1D.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size= 5 , strides= 1 , activation='relu'))
model_1D.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size= 2, strides= 2))
model_1D.add(Flatten())
model_1D.add(Dense(7 , activation='relu')) # K
model_1D.add(Dense(6 , activation='softmax')) 
model_1D.summary()
model_1D.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_1D.fit(X_train1 , y_train1,epochs=100,validation_data=( X_valid1,y_valid1))
```

Where is the error and how can i solve this issue?

```
X_train1D.shape ---> (7380, 128000)
```

Comment: The shape of your input data `X_train1` is incorrect. It should have a shape of (b, 128000, 7380) where `b` is your batch size.

Comment: But in this paper doesn't mention batch size but i did what you said and trying to reshape  X_train1 to (-1,128000,7380) but it give me this error : cannot reshape array of size 604544000 into shape (128000,7380) @Toukenize

Comment: Ask the author or experiment with your own. The error is because of your input array size. It is (4723, 128000), which expands to 604544000. Check if you preprocessed and fetched the data correctly.